How to inform users on Scan gun functionality
I am working on a project where there will be an input file with three types of users interacting to it.

Enter values manually.
User will have barcode scan gun and scans it .
Scan Barcode which opens a camera.

The input field is set in a way it has no real estate to give help text.
How should I inform users that u can use your scan gun to scan barcode.
Also since the UI is on desktop, What are the negative impacts of using scan barcode on Desktop ?
Thank You

Please add as much context as possible. Do you have a design that can be added?

One very simple solution would be to add icons inside the input field at the far right end for example indicating a "scan gun" and a "camera".
Alternatively add a prompt text (the lightgrey default text) like "enter or scan code"
In the end you will need to have some place where to explain the functionality, though. Either in the manual or maybe by clicking on the small icons. But the icons alone might not ensure that every user finds them.
Scan Barcode on desktop PC:
Well, you need to keep in mind that desktop computers normally do not have a camera equipped. If your work environment does not make that a necessity at least. Only external cameras - or if your software is used on a tablet or notebook - would make it possible to use a camera for that purpose.
How the scan gun is connected, I cannot tell you. Probably by cable or wireless somehow. Not all desktop PCs have a WiFi or Bluetooth adapter either. Only notebooks/tablets have them.
